# Get BigDecimal value from Grails params

Tags: grails

I am writing a reporting functionality for a Domain object in grails. There is field "balance" which is BigDecimal. I am having trouble writing the query. Appreciate any help.

View

```
<tr class="prop">
<td valign="top" class="name">
<label for="balance"><g:message code="sale.balance.label" default="Balance" /></label>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="value">
<g:textField name="balance" value="${params.balance}" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
def c = Sale.createCriteria()
def saleList = c.list {
if(params.id)
    idEq(java.lang.Long.parseLong(params.id))
if(params.customerName)
    like('customerName', params.customerName+"%")
if(params.customerPh)
    like('customerPh', params.customerPh+"%")
if(params.balance)
    ge('balance', java.math.BigDecimal(params.balance))
if(params.totalSale)
    ge('totalSale', params.totalSale)
```

Exception

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: java for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
    at colorthread.SaleController$_closure9_closure23.doCall(SaleController.groovy:289)
    at colorthread.SaleController$_closure9_closure23.doCall(SaleController.groovy)

Comment: unrelated - java.lang.* is auto-imported in Groovy (and Java) and java.math.BigDecimal is auto-imported in Groovy, so you don't need the full packages there

Comment: Thanks Burt...will keep that in mind. I am newbie grails developer and I follow your blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the *new* keyword:

```
    ge('balance', new java.math.BigDecimal(params.balance))
```